# Understanding scoping of nested functions

Tags: r, function, lexical-scope

I'm attempting to refactor a script by splitting it into multiple functions, having a main function and "help functions". Here I stumbled upon a problem which can be reduced to the following example:

```
g <- function(a,b){       # help function
    a^2 + b^2 - c
}

f <- function(a,b,c,d){   # main function
    g(a,b)
}
```

The problem here is, that `f` cannot be computed because `g` does not know what `c` is, but why is that the case?

I've read [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping) that if R doesn't know a variable/argument in a function, it searches for that missing variable/argument in the outer function/environment.

Why does `g` still not know the value `c` which gets declared by `f`?

Comment: g needs to be 3-arity and accept c as a parameter

Comment: The example and your question are both clear, but I argue that even starting down this road is indicative of bad programming practice: assuming that `g()` can find `c` still renders `g()` a not-to-reproducible function. That is, its output is not strictly a definition of the two parameters passed to it. If you are writing these functions, then write them correctly: ***never*** assume a variable exists outside of the function's definition, or you will have at times very-difficult-to-troubleshoot bugs that perform differently with same args in different environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R uses lexical scoping which means that if a function needs to reference an object not defined in that function it looks at the environment in which the function was *defined*, not the caller.  In the question g is defined in the global environment so that is where g looks for c.

Also note that in R we would not call the functions in the question nested functions. Rather what is nested is the calls, not the functions.  In (3) below we show nested functions.

**1)** We can reset a function's environment in which case it will think it was defined in that environment.

```
g <- function(a,b){       # help function
    a^2 + b^2 - c
}

f <- function(a,b,c,d){   # main function
    environment(g) <- environment()
    g(a,b)
}

f(1, 2, 3, 4)
## [1] 2
```

**2)** Another possibility is to explicitly tell it which environment to search using envir$c (where envir is the desired environment) or get("c", envir)  or with(envir, c) .  envir$c will look into envir.  The other two will look there and if not found will look into ancestor environments.  (Each environment has a parent or the emptyenv().  This is distinct from the call stack.)

```
g <- function(a, b, envir = parent.frame()){       # help function
    a^2 + b^2 - envir$c
}

f <- function(a,b,c,d){   # main function
    g(a,b)
}

f(1, 2, 3, 4)
## [1] 2
```

**3)** We can nest the functions so that g is defined in f.

```
f <- function(a,b,c,d){   # main function
    g <- function(a,b){       # help function
        a^2 + b^2 - c
    }
    g(a,b)
}

f(1, 2, 3, 4)
## [1] 2
```

**4)** Of course you could just pass c and avoid all these problems.

```
g <- function(a, b, c) { 
    a^2 + b^2 - c
}

f <- function(a, b, c, d) {   # main function
    g(a, b, c)
}

f(1, 2, 3, 4)
## [1] 2
```

Comment: The benefits of #4 are huge. It's much easier to test and reason about your code when you write pure functions.

Comment: A helpful post, but could you give an example of #4 -- explicitly passing the object

Comment: Have added that.